# how to write a command to a process using batch

Tags: batch-file, command-line, process, console

Say i have a process server.bat open that was waiting for an input. 
How could i make another process write.bat write to that server.bat process?

for instance a server.bat process that has can respond to 2 commands: save-on and save-off.
I want to take a backup of the files the server.bat is using but the files get corrupted if the server is in save-on mode, what i want to do is sent the save-off command to the process, take a backup and then write save-on to re-enable saving.

I've tried stopping the process, backing up and restarting it, but that usually ended up in even more file corruption, as well as the inconvenience for the people currently connected to the server

--EDIT

I want to write a string to a command line, in this case an instance of the `server.bat`.

A simple example:

**server.bat** (which cannot be changed)

```
@ECHO off
TITLE Server
:start
SET /P Command="Command: "
ECHO %Command%
GOTO :start
```

**write.bat**

```
@ECHO off
START server.bat
:Loop
TIMEOUT /t 5
:: So how do I target the instance of server.bat there?
ECHO "foo"> (...)?
GOTO :Loop
```

Both files are not the actual files and just serve the purpose of clarifying my question.
You first execute the `write.bat` which in turn opens the `server.bat` and should write to it.

Comment: Look into Wscript's `AppActivate` and `SendKeys` methods.  There's no pure batch solution of which I'm aware, but you could use a batch / JScript hybrid to accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it is including a write.vbs file:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.AppActivate "More Specific Title X"
For I = 0 to WScript.Arguments.Count - 1
    WshShell.SendKeys WScript.Arguments(I) & " "
Next
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

**write.bat**

```
@ECHO off
START server.bat
:Loop
TIMEOUT /t 5
START write.vbs "foo"
GOTO :Loop
```

**server.bat**

```
@ECHO off
TITLE More Specific Title X
:start
SET /P Command=
GOTO :start
```

**WARNING:** The title should be the same as the string specified in write.vbs and it should be specific because it indicates the name of the process.

Another way to do it in pure batch is creating a text file is:

**server.bat**

```
@ECHO off
:start
TIMEOUT /t 1
IF NOT EXIST %1 goto start
FOR /f "delims=" %%I IN (%1) DO ECHO %%I
DEL /q %1
GOTO :start
```

**write.bat**

```
@ECHO off
SET ServerFile="%TMP%\WriteToServer"
DEL /q write.txt
START server.bat %ServerFile%
:Loop
TIMEOUT /t 5
ECHO "foo"> %ServerFile%
GOTO :Loop
```

The second way does not instantly receive message, but you can make the check time less than 1 second. You could easily find on the web a command tool similar to "TIMEOUT" but in milliseconds.